# Is it possible to send email using configuration from another shared hosting?

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

My Laravel Apps cannot send email using another shared hosting configuration.

I'm developing laravel app (Laravel 5.7), one of my apps function is to send email after register new account. I have deployed my apps to my VPS and I have account on a shared hosting. I used my shared hosting configuration for sending email and I have added the config to my .env file, like

`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

`MAIL_HOST=mail.embara.id`

`MAIL_PORT=465`

`MAIL_USERNAME="username"`

`MAIL_PASSWORD="password"`

`MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS="FROM"`

`MAIL_FROM_NAME="FROM NAME"`

`MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null`

but nothing happen, only failed (I am using queue, and i have tested using mailtrap.io, everything works fine)

Anyone knows what is wrong with my config?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think you need `ssl`, try this:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.embara.id
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=noreply@embara.id # <-- full email address
MAIL_PASSWORD=secret
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl # <-- This
```

Comment: thanks, your solution works! But, my email considered as a spam, could you help me?

Comment: Is the website domain name not the same as the email domain? Usually spam checks do a reverse ip check. Go to intodns.com and insert your domain then go down to `Reverse MX A records (PTR)`, do you have a green checkmark? Or blue or red?

Comment: Did you get it right? You can always use mailgun :)

Comment: sorry for late answer, no the website not same with the email domain. Yes, I got red checkmark.

Comment: Yeah then you wont really get away from the spam folder.. But if this is the correct answer, can you please mark it as correct for the next guy that views this question?